# SiI 3114 vs. ICH7R RAID performance

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid, benchmarking

I just got two new WD5000AAKS 500GB SATA 3.0Gb/s drives, and I need to put them in a RAID-0 array (I know that motherboard-RAID generally isn't the best for speed increases, but I have little choice). This RAID array will be just storing backups on a Linux server, and trust me, I know first-hand that RAID is **not** backup.<sup>*</sup>

My server is using a recycled D975XBX Intel motherboard (OEM is Alienware) with a Core 2 Duo E6600 @ 2.4 GHz. The motherboard has two groups of 4 SATA ports:

- 4 controlled by the ICH7R with Intel on-motherboard RAID @ 3.0Gb/s
- 4 controlled by a Silicon Image (SiI) 3114 controller @ 1.5Gb/s

My question is, for RAID0, which would be faster, using the built-in RAID with the Intel ports, or using the Silicon Image RAID?

As far as I can tell, the ICH7R uses the CPU for all of its calculations and RAID processing (and my server is very low-load so it wouldn't really matter), but I don't know if the SiI 3114 controller does any of the RAID calculations or if the operations are left to the BIOS & CPU. I suppose I could setup the drives on each and do some benchmarking with `bonnie++`, but I figured that I should ask here first. Cheers!
<sub>* That's not even really relevant since it's a RAID0 array; not meant for redundancy of any sort.</sub>

---

**EDIT**: I just found [this article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/1932/9) from AnandTech with a review of the motherboard. It would appear that the ICH7R has better performance without RAID, but the article doesn't contain any tests with a RAID set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After performing some (rudimentary) benchmarks with `hdparm` and `bonnie++`, and reading [this forum thread](http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?t=190550) on ICHR vs SiI, I have come to the conclusion that the ICH7R Intel Matrix RAID controller is *slightly* faster than the SiI 3114 controller for sequential reads, and *much* faster with random reads under RAID-0 conditions with two WD5000AAKS drives.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Sil controller at all. It's connected trough PCI bus at 33 MHz, so the maximum speed you can achieve is around 133 MiB/sec. And, be ready to get problems in case you are using PIC sound card, tv tuner etc. I was so disappointed. Intel made it really bad.